# Unexpected behaviour of bevel

Tags: bevel

I made sure there are no redundant vertices. It is one object. I expect it to bevel (Ctrl + B) like in the first picture, but what it does is on the second. Did the bevel tool change in 2.9x?

[image: Expectation]

[image: What It Does]

Comment: Check to make you're normals are all facing the right way (select all in edit mode > Mesh > Normals > Recalculate Outside)

Comment: This worked. Many thanks!